# How to input A Table name using User_input in Mysql Using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

## Enter DATA Into DATABASE

```
import MySQLdb
import time
import datetime
import calendar
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
print "Local current time :", localtime
```

## Open database connection

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","attendence" )
```

## prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

```
cursor = db.cursor()
```

## Enter subject

```
subject=raw_input("Enter Subject Name:")
```

## Drop table if it already exist using execute() m ethod.

```
sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s"%(subject)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

## Create table as per requirem ent

```
sql1= """CREATE TABLE %s (Sl_No. INT(200),NAME CHAR(20))"""%(subject)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

## disconnect from server

```
db.close()
```

Comment: This is bad practice. You should never take raw input and pass it into any SQL statements. Prepared statements should have values passed in via the execute function.

Comment: But, How can i create table my own choice??

Comment: For example, you could define a naming pattern for the tables, some static part and some dynamic part coming from the user input. The user input needs validation though, e.g. it should only allow for letters and numbers. These two parts are then combined to form the actual table name. That way you drastically minimize the vulnerability to SQL injection attacks and somewhat obfuscate the actual names of your DB entities. Still, not the best of ideas to do such a thing.

Comment: Ok, fine i understood the problem.

Comment: But,can i create table my own choice??

Comment: Wait, you don't just want to take the table name from the input but the column definitions (and constraints) as well?  In that case, I think this question is way too broad. Are you planning to write your own phpmyadmin or something?

Answer (score 0):

Surely,you can do so.But it donot recommend.And your code have some error,such as `Sl_No.` is invalid col name.
So i change your code a little.

```
import MySQLdb
import time
import datetime
import calendar
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
print ("Local current time :", localtime)
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","attendence" )
cursor = db.cursor()
subject = raw_input("Enter Subject Name:")
cursor.execute("show tables")
dele = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {tab}".format(tab=subject)
cre  = """CREATE TABLE {tab} (Sl_No INT(200),NAME CHAR(20))""".format(tab=subject)

def commit(sql):
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()

if subject.strip() in [tab[0] for tab in cursor.fetchall()]:
    commit(dele)
    commit(cre)
else:
    commit(cre)
db.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","reverend","TESTDB" )